# "not finding" vs "didn't find"

Tags: grammar

> I groped for a handkerchief, and **not finding** one,pulled off my apron
>   and handed it to him to wipe his face.

Why does this use "not finding" in a past tense sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and not finding one

*finding* in this case is a present participle, but "present" with a participle is generally understood relatively to the main verb.

Thus a present participle indicates an action occurring (or not occurring in this case) at the same time as the main verb(s) (groped, pulled, handed)